# Can I create a loop to update SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have 6 tables in my `sql.db` file. And I was wondering if it would be possible to create a loop to go through each column within this 6 tables, and convert the values to `NULL` if the cell value is `-`

**Code I currently have**

```
for each_item in df.index:  
# Note: The name of the tables in the database is the variable 'each_item'
    pd.Dataframe.to_sql(df, con=engine, name=each_item, if_exists='append', index=False)

    # The below code does not work. And I have no idea why
    for each_columns in df.columns:
        connection.execute('UPDATE each_item SET each_columns = NULL WHERE each_columns = '-')
```

This seems to produce an error.

How should I be coding it such that I am able to go through all the `tables` in the `sql.db`, and update each and every `column` in the `tables`, if the cell value = `-`?

To be more specific, The error I got says that it cant locate the table. `no such table: each_item`

Comment: tbh id just put it in a while loop

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help me with my issue. It seem not to be able to locate the `tables` if i put the table names in a variable

Comment: Is it connecting to the server?

Comment: where are the names of your 6 tables? what kind of SQL DB you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are quite a few problems in your code. Let's address each at a time:

1. `pd.DataFrame.to_sql` stands for `your_dataframe.to_sql` in this case, `df.to_sql`. It is a method on a `DataFrame` object, and that object is the `DataFrame` you created. If this confuses you, please read about classes and methods in Python.
2. `to_sql` takes its first argument as table name, then connection, then schema name, and finally the if_exists and the index kwag
3. It would be better if you did all conversions before you tried to write to SQL. That just makes things cleaner. Further, if you DataFrame is properly dtyped, NaN values will automatically get converted to the appropriate NULL value representation for the database engine in question.

If you consider all the points above, this is how it should be done:

```
for each_item in df.index: # I would avoid a syntax like this. Better to have the DataFrames in a list, than iterate through a DataFrame
    df.loc[each_item].to_sql(name=each_item, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False) # Here again, I would avoid using the name engine for a connection to a database engine
```

However, the success of the above code depends on your DataFrame being properly data typed, which I conclude it is not because you asked this question. If you edit your question with a sample of your DataFrame, I would be able to help you get your dtypes correct.

---

Ps. If your DataFrame is created as a result of your previous question about DataFrame merging, then let me know and I will provide you with a comprehensive solution to both questions here. But do edit this question with data from that question so that people reading this question will not be stumped.